# Getting Error "(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: <func_name> is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):1:1)" on clicking delete button

Tags: javascript

I tried developing an expense tracker app using Javascript, in which the users keep entering the data. I also want to have a delete button which deletes the entered information. I've successfully added the information provided by the users but unable to delete any single information entered by the users. I'm getting the error ***"(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteExpense is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):1:1)"*** after clicking the `delete` button. Requesting your help. Plese refer my code below.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Form validation
                function validate() {
                    if (document.myForm.empId.value == "") {
                        alert("Please provide your Employee ID!");
                        document.myForm.empId.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (document.myForm.empName.value == "") {
                        alert("Please provide your Name!");
                        document.myForm.empName.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (document.myForm.PaymentMode.value == "") {
                        alert("Select your Payment Mode!");
                        document.myForm.PaymentMode.focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (document.myForm.Date.value == "") {
                        alert("Please provide the Date!");
                        document.myForm.Date.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (document.myForm.Bill.value == "") {
                        alert("Please provide your Bill Amount!");
                        document.myForm.Bill.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                let id = document.getElementById("id").innerText;
                let empId = document.getElementById("empID").value;
                let name = document.getElementById("name").innerText;
                let empName = document.getElementById("empname").value;
                let using = document.getElementById("using").innerText;
                let mode = document.getElementById("payment-mode").value;
                let day = document.getElementById("day").innerText;
                let date = document.getElementById("date").value;
                let amount = document.getElementById("amount").innerText;
                let bill = document.getElementById("bill").value;
                let array = [
                    [id, empId],
                    [name, empName],
                    [using, mode],
                    [day, date],
                    [amount, bill],
                ];
                let expenseList = Object.fromEntries(array);
                const expenseTable = document.getElementById("expenseTable");

                function output() {
                    if (validate()) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(expenseList).length; i++) {
                            expenseTable.innerHTML += `
                        <tr>
                            <td>${expenseList[id]}</td>
                            <td>${expenseList[name]}</td>
                            <td>${expenseList[using]}</td>
                            <td>${expenseList[day]}</td>
                            <td>$${expenseList[amount]}</td>
                            <td><a class="deleteButton" onclick="deleteExpense(${expenseList[id]})">
                                Delete</td>
                        </tr>
                    `;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                    const deleteExpense = (id) => {
                        for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(expenseList).length; j++) {
                            if (expenseList[id] == id) {
                                delete expenseList.id;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    deleteExpense();
                }
                output();
            });
```

```css
.table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Expense Tracker Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="employee-info">
            <form
                class="expenesesForm"
                name="myForm"
                onsubmit="return(validate());"
                method="POST"
                action=""
            >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="id">Employee ID:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="empID" name="empId" type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="name">Name:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="empname" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="empName" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="using">Payment Mode:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="payment-mode" name="PaymentMode">
                                <option class="" value="" selected disabled>
                                    Select from the list
                                </option>
                                <option class="mode" value="card">Card</option>
                                <option class="mode" value="cheque">Cheque</option>
                                <option class="mode" value="cash">Cash</option>
                                <option class="mode" value="other">Other</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="day">Date of Transaction:</td>
                        <td><input id="date" type="date" name="Date" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="amount">Amount:</td>
                        <td><input id="bill" type="number" name="Bill" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <br />
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Mode of Transaction</th>
                        <th>Date of Transaction</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="expenseTable"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

**Expected Output:**
On clicking the `delete` button in the table, it should delete one row of information entered by the user.

Comment: Don't use `onclick="deleteExpense"` since `deleteExpense` is not in the global scope. After defining the function use a `addEventListener`?

Comment: You're also going to want to fix that `for` loop looking for the expense to delete; the index should be `j` not `id`

Comment: Understood the concept. But unable to execute so..! Could you please provide a code for that? Please don't mind. I'm kind of new to JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reference the function outside its scope. The snippet below works, but I do not know much about your other requirements, so if this approach is breaking something, then please let me know.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Form validation
                function validate() {
                    if (document.myForm.empId.value == "") {
                        alert("Please provide your Employee ID!");
                        document.myForm.empId.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (document.myForm.empName.value == "") {
                        alert("Please provide your Name!");
                        document.myForm.empName.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (document.myForm.PaymentMode.value == "") {
                        alert("Select your Payment Mode!");
                        document.myForm.PaymentMode.focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (document.myForm.Date.value == "") {
                        alert("Please provide the Date!");
                        document.myForm.Date.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (document.myForm.Bill.value == "") {
                        alert("Please provide your Bill Amount!");
                        document.myForm.Bill.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                let id = document.getElementById("id").innerText;
                let empId = document.getElementById("empID").value;
                let name = document.getElementById("name").innerText;
                let empName = document.getElementById("empname").value;
                let using = document.getElementById("using").innerText;
                let mode = document.getElementById("payment-mode").value;
                let day = document.getElementById("day").innerText;
                let date = document.getElementById("date").value;
                let amount = document.getElementById("amount").innerText;
                let bill = document.getElementById("bill").value;
                let array = [
                    [id, empId],
                    [name, empName],
                    [using, mode],
                    [day, date],
                    [amount, bill],
                ];
                let expenseList = Object.fromEntries(array);
                const expenseTable = document.getElementById("expenseTable");

                function output() {
                    if (validate()) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(expenseList).length; i++) {
                            expenseTable.innerHTML += `
                        <tr>
                            <td>${expenseList[id]}</td>
                            <td>${expenseList[name]}</td>
                            <td>${expenseList[using]}</td>
                            <td>${expenseList[day]}</td>
                            <td>$${expenseList[amount]}</td>
                            <td><a class="deleteButton">
                                Delete</td>
                        </tr>
                    `;
                        for (let i = 0; i < expenseTable.children.length; i++)expenseTable.children[i].querySelector('.deleteButton').addEventListener("click", function() {
                            this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                        });
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                    /*const deleteExpense = (id) => {
                        for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(expenseList).length; j++) {
                            if (expenseList[id] == id) {
                                delete expenseList.id;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    deleteExpense();*/
                }
                output();
            });
```

```css
.table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Expense Tracker Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="employee-info">
            <form
                class="expenesesForm"
                name="myForm"
                onsubmit="return(validate());"
                method="POST"
                action=""
            >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="id">Employee ID:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="empID" name="empId" type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="name">Name:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="empname" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="empName" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="using">Payment Mode:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="payment-mode" name="PaymentMode">
                                <option class="" value="" selected disabled>
                                    Select from the list
                                </option>
                                <option class="mode" value="card">Card</option>
                                <option class="mode" value="cheque">Cheque</option>
                                <option class="mode" value="cash">Cash</option>
                                <option class="mode" value="other">Other</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="day">Date of Transaction:</td>
                        <td><input id="date" type="date" name="Date" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="amount">Amount:</td>
                        <td><input id="bill" type="number" name="Bill" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <br />
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Mode of Transaction</th>
                        <th>Date of Transaction</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="expenseTable"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Lajos Arpad, It worked as expected. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`deleteExpense` is defined **inside** your event listener function.

`onclick` attributes execute in the **global** scope.

It isn't defined in the scope you are trying to access.

---

This is one of many problems with `onclick` attributes. Use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Understood the concept. But unable to execute so..! Could you please provide a code for that? Please don't mind. I'm kind of new to JS.